# Protractor : Click on webpage to save number input

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to automate application using the protractor (for angular application), I am providing some numbers in the input field (type=number) but have to click anywhere on the webpage to save changes. How to click anywhere on the webpage.

Comment: I guess even on tab out, the value should be saved.If it works with tab out, then you need to do something like `input.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB)`

Comment: Yes it worked, Thank you, implemented this on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide html.

I usually click on footer if there is id by which I can select it.

But you can click on any element on page.

Comment: Hi sanja thanks for answer, although I can't post html here due to my org security policy but will include this solution in my code.